# Ember-data observe confusion

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model like this:

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  items: DS.hasMany('item', {async: true}),
  itemCount: function() {
    return this.get('items').get('length');
  }.property('items')
});
```

and it seems I cannot use "property" there if I want to have the UI update everytime a user adds or removes items.

From what I can tell I should be using "observes", but when I use that in place of "property" the handlebars {{itemCount}} tag just renders the function itself as a string.

Any help on getting this to render properly is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply use :

```
{{items.length}}
```

in your handlebars template.

There's absolutely no need for an observer, computed properties do updates themselves.

And if you really want a computed property named itemCount, it would be :

```
itemCount: function() {
  return this.get('items.length');
}.property('items.length')
```

Or even better :

```
itemCount: Ember.computed.alias('items.length')
```

Comment: Ok, so all of these worked, but why *doesn't* my code work? Your second solution seems to be almost no different from my approach.

Comment: If the "itemCount" computed property depends only on 'items' and not on 'items.length', the computed property value will only be updated when the 'items' property is set; for example to another array, or null. => Your code needs to be more explicit.

Comment: Ah yes, I see! Thanks for the explanation. This helps me understand ember much better.

Answer (score 1):

Like @florent-blanvillain said, just use `Ember.computed.alias`. But in the future, when writing computed properties based on arrays, you need to use the `@each` syntax to get it to respond to changes in property values:

```
itemCount: function() {
  return this.get('items').filterBy('isSelected');
}.property('items.@each.isSelected')
```

Something like that. See [the docs on computed properties](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/) for more info.

Comment: Sure! If you found both answers helpful you can also upvote them.